# Differentiation of a floor function using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: derivatives, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came acroos the following function today which gave different results for its differentiation. Here is it

$$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ at }x \in [1,2]$$.

In the above function, the value of f(x) is always 1. Lets consider f'(x) =0, for all x $\in$ (1,2). But when I use Mean Value Theorem(MVT), I get,

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1} = 1 \neq 0$$

My guess: Floor function creates discontinuity, while MVT checks for values in a continuous function. Is the contradictory answer justified by my guess?.

Thanks

Comment: The mean value theorem requires the function to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$. Your function is not continuous on $[1,2]$.

Comment: I thought MVT has as hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable on the interval? If $f$ is not continuous at a point, it is certainly not differentiable there.

Comment: @MPW You don't need differentiability at the endpoints, but you do need continuity there.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I meant on the open interval. And I see I was mistaken, my bad. The function is differentiable there.

Comment: @MPW The given function is indeed differentiable on $(1,2)$. (It is constant there.)